# Error al iniciar aplicacion en ionic 3

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-framework

cuando inicio la aplicacion aparece el siguiente error

ionic the connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file ///android_asset/www/index.html)

Tengo en el config.xlm

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000>
```

pero se demora 25 segundos en cargar esa app(Mucho tiempo, demasiado)

En index.html no tengo ningun enlace externo es decir algo como
https://maps.googleapis.co

he buscado pero siempre encuentro la misma solucion. 
colocar esto

Answer (score 0):

Podrías documentar mas tu pregunta poniendo capturas de pantalla del error en especifico

Según lo que leo es posible que :
1 no tengas agregada alguna librería en app.module
2. El puerto del servidor este ocupado lo otro programa(cuyo caso podrías solucionar con ionic serve 9100)
3. La nueva versión de ido esta dando error. Debes instalar una antigua

Etc.

Postea capturas para poder ayudarte bien.

Un saludo